# Sort columns by names (only specific columns)

Tags: r, dataframe

For example I have dataframe like this :

```
test = data.frame(C = c(0, 2, 4, 7, 8), A = c(4, 2, 4, 7, 8), B = c(1, 3, 8, 3, 2), Z = c(6, 7, 3, 3, 1), D = c(1, 8, 9, 9, 5))
```

and I want sort only the 3 last columns by names. I try this one, but it's not working :

```
test[3:5] <- test[3:5][ , order(names(test[3:5]))]
```

The result should be like this:

```
C     A     B     D     Z
0     4     1     1     6
2     2     3     8     7
...   ...   ...   ...   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

One option via `dplyr::select()`

```
dplyr::select(test, names(test)[1:2], sort(names(test)[3:5]))
```

**Output**:

```
 C A B D Z
1 0 4 1 1 6
2 2 2 3 8 7
3 4 4 8 9 3
4 7 7 3 9 3
5 8 8 2 5 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R (distinctly uglier than the `dplyr::select()` solution):

```r
n <- names(test)
nc <- ncol(test)
test[, c(n[1:(nc - 3)], sort(n[(nc - 2):nc]))]
#  C A B D Z
#1 0 4 1 1 6
#2 2 2 3 8 7
#3 4 4 8 9 3
#4 7 7 3 9 3
#5 8 8 2 5 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
test[c(1:2, order(names(test[3:5]))+2)]
```

A two step Base

```
#Move the data
test[3:5]<-test[3:5][order(names(test[3:5]))]
#Rearange the column names
names(test)<-c(names(test[1:2]), names(test[3:5][order(names(test[3:5]))]))
```

Answer (score 0):

base R

```
cbind(test[,1:2],test[,sort(names(test)[3:5])])
```

or (slightly faster)

```
test[,c(names(test)[1:2],sort(names(test)[-(1:2)]))]
```

Output:

```
  C A B D Z
1 0 4 1 1 6
2 2 2 3 8 7
3 4 4 8 9 3
4 7 7 3 9 3
5 8 8 2 5 1
```